# How to convert nested foreach for category tree into recursion?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I need to make this nested loop into recursion because I don't know how much depth will the category tree have.

PHP code:

```
$categories = [];
foreach ($category_tree as $category_1) {
    $categories[$category_1['id_category']] = $category_1['name'];
    if (count($category_1['children'])) {
        foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) {
            $categories[$category_2['id_category']] = $category_1['name'] . ' > ' . $category_2['name'];
            if (count($category_2['children'])) {
                foreach ($category_2['children'] as $category_3) {
                    $categories[$category_3['id_category']] = $category_1['name'] . ' > ' . $category_2['name'] . ' > ' . $category_3['name'];
                    if (count($category_3['children'])) {
                        foreach ($category_3['children'] as $category_4) {
                            $categories[$category_4['id_category']] = $category_1['name'] . ' > ' . $category_2['name'] . ' > ' . $category_3['name'] . ' > ' . $category_4['name'];
                            if (count($category_4['children'])) {
                                foreach ($category_4['children'] as $category_5) {
                                    $categories[$category_5['id_category']] = $category_1['name'] . ' > ' . $category_2['name'] . ' > ' . $category_3['name'] . ' > ' . $category_4['name'] . ' > ' . $category_5['name'];
                                    if (count($category_4['children'])) {

                                    }
                                } 
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the result should be like this:

```
Array
(
  [2] => Home
  [3] => Home > Clothes
  [4] => Home > Clothes > Men
  [6] => Home > Women's Clothing
  [7] => Home > Women's Clothing > Stationery
  [10] => Home > Women's Clothing > Jackets
  [88] => Home > Women's Clothing > Jackets > Women's Sports Teams
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! More details are necessary here. What does your input `$category_tree` look like? What is the code supposed to do? Please post a runnable [mcve] of your attempt and clearly describe the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide `$category_tree`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this, but since you didn't provide the input, I couldn't test it.

```
function get_category_map(&$tree, &$out, $pre = '')
{
    foreach ($tree as &$cat)
    {
        $out[$cat['id_category']] = $pre . $cat['name'];
        if (count($cat['children']))
            get_category_map($cat['children'], $out, "{$pre}{$cat['name']} > ");
    }
}

$categories = [];
get_category_map($category_tree, $categories);
print_r($categories);
```